# Azure function app reload on change does not work with v4 model

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions, hot-reload

Can not make Azure Function to reload and pick up changes on source code change.

I'm using out of the box launch task to start local server and have `npm` `tsc -w` script running in watch mode. When the code is changes, is can see the changes in `/dist` folder, and `function: host start` terminal prints `Worker process started and initialized.`
but request to the function does not reflect the changes.

I've added

```
{
    "watchDirectories": [ "dist" ]
}
```

but it did not help either.

Not tottaly related but I also have tried to add `"languageWorkers:node:arguments": "--inspect=5858"` to `local.setting.json` and changing the port specified in launch task to 5858 but with no result.

What do I miss?

Comment: there is a bug for that: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9185

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` from **local.settings.json** when your making changes to your code locally or while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Watch Configuration: Ensure that your watch configuration is correctly set up to monitor changes in the dist folder. From your description, it seems like you've already added "watchDirectories": ["dist"] to your local.settings.json file, which is the correct approach.